# Datastax QueryBuilder cannot find 'Contains' clause

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Updated Cassandra driver core jar to version 2.2.0-rc1 from 2.1.7. I have a statement like :

```
Statement select = QueryBuilder.select().all().from(keyspace, tableName).where(QueryBuilder.contains("tags", list.get(0)));
```

Cannot find **QueryBuilder.contains**. Do we now have some alternative for contains clause? How to use contains for new updated driver?

Answer (score 1):

Java Driver 2.2+ no longer provides static methods for QueryBuilder for creating queries.  Instead you [now must construct a QueryBuilder](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.2/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/QueryBuilder.html#QueryBuilder-com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster-) instance providing a Cluster instance, i.e.:

```java
Statement select = new QueryBuilder(cluster).select().all().from(keyspace, tableName).where(QueryBuilder.contains("tags", list.get(0)));
```

There has been discussion that providing the Cluster instance may not always be required (it's mainly useful for determining key routing and value serialization), so this may change back to the way it exists in java-driver 2.1.

The contains method still remains static as it is part of query criteria, but not for constructing the beginning of the query (i.e. select, delete, etc.).

Comment: 2.2.0-rc1 still has static QueryBuilder. Version 2.2.0-rc2 + requires instance.